# how to getpreferences in other activity

Tags: android, textview, sharedpreferences, seekbar, togglebutton

I made a shared preferences for my seekbar and my togglebutton in one activity but what I can't do is how to get this preferences into other activity so when I change the seekbar all the textsize in all activities will change and when I toggle the button all the colors of textview and layouts will change in other activity

```
public class CollectionPrayersTextActivity extends Activity {

// Colors Shared Preferences
public SharedPreferences tprefs;
private ToggleButton toggle;
private LinearLayout linear;
// Text Size Shared Preferences
private SharedPreferences prefs;
public static TextView textview;
private SeekBar seekbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    // Remove notification bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    Window window = getWindow();
    // Unlock the device if locked
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    // Turn screen on if off
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    // Keep screen on
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    // Transition between activities
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.incoming, R.anim.outgoing);
    // On Create
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_collectionprayers_text);
    // Determine The Tools
    seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarcollectionprayerstext);
    textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_collectionprayers_txt);
    toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearcollection);
    // Toogle Share Preferences
    SharedPreferences tprefs = getSharedPreferences(
            "com.e_orthodoxy.orthodox_prayers", MODE_PRIVATE);
    toggle.setChecked(tprefs.getBoolean("Switchable", true));
    if (toggle.isChecked()) {
        textview.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        textview.setShadowLayer(0, 0, 0, Color.WHITE);

    } else {

        textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        textview.setShadowLayer(0, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);

    }
    // Get Extra From Another Activity
    Intent n = getIntent();
    String mrng = n.getStringExtra("key");
    textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(mrng));
    // SeekBar Preferences
    prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    float fs = prefs.getFloat("fontsize", 40);
    seekbar.setProgress((int) fs);
    textview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, seekbar.getProgress());
    // Programming SeekBar
    seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefs.edit();
            ed.putFloat("fontsize", textview.getTextSize());
            ed.commit();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            textview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, progress);
        }
    });
    // Programming ToggleButton
    toggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (toggle.isChecked()) {
                textview.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                textview.setShadowLayer(0, 0, 0, Color.WHITE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(
                        "com.e_orthodoxy.orthodox_prayers", MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .edit();
                editor.putBoolean("Switchable", true);
                editor.commit();

            } else {

                textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                textview.setShadowLayer(0, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(
                        "com.e_orthodoxy.orthodox_prayers", MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .edit();
                editor.putBoolean("Switchable", false);
                editor.commit();

            }
        }
    });
}

public void c_default(View V) {
    textview.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Vanilla));
    linear.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Maroon));
    textview.setShadowLayer((float) 1.5, 2, 2, Color.BLACK);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent_e3tiraf_back = new Intent(
            CollectionPrayersTextActivity.this,
            CollectionPrayersActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent_e3tiraf_back);
    finish();
}
}
```

any help????

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `SharedPreference` in the another activity in the following manner.

```
SharedPreferences tprefs = getSharedPreferences(
        "com.e_orthodoxy.orthodox_prayers", MODE_PRIVATE);
String textSize = tprefs.getString("fontsize",null);
```

Here textSize is the size of your textview which you want in next activity.

Comment: well if I have in the other activity a seekbar how to let the seekbar have the same value of the seekbar in the first activity
is your method work or I should do something else

Comment: @RoyJalbout You have to get the value of `SeekBar` from previous activity and use in your new activity.

Comment: ok and for the code you provided where should I put it to let the size changed in the other activity

Answer (score 1):

```
SharedPreferences mPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
                "com.e_orthodoxy.orthodox_prayers", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPref.edit();
                Boolean userid=mPref.getBoolean("Switchable", false)
```

Comment: where should I put this in my next activity

Comment: onCreate you can put.It will work anywhere,since sharedpreference is use to store data

Comment: when I put it the context and the .getBoolean is underlined with red color
context = context cannot be resolved
getBoolean = The method getBoolean(String, boolean) in the type SharedPreferences is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)

Comment: context still the same, ?? explain it

Comment: context still underlined the error is context cannot be resolved

Comment: you can use this in place of context and what are you storing in the

Comment: I put this instead of context but when I open the next activity nothing is change

Comment: please explain me in detail

Comment: you tell me to put this instead of context so I put it then I run my application and I enter in the first activity and I pressed the toggle button to change the colors and when I enter to the second activity where I put your code nothing is changed the colors still the default one

Comment: Check what this variable is retrieving:-mPref.getBoolean("Switchable", false)

Comment: man it's done look what I put in the second activity in onCreate
SharedPreferences tprefs = getSharedPreferences(
    "com.e_orthodoxy.orthodox_prayers", MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean colors = tprefs.getBoolean("Switchable", false);
        if (colors == true){
         textview.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
   linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
   textview.setShadowLayer(0, 0, 0, Color.WHITE);
        }else if (colors == false) {
         textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
   linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
   textview.setShadowLayer(0, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
        }

Answer (score 0):

Firstly question is not clear.But if u press back button 
and all get changed as you have mention write the textview 
color and size change code in onResume().
and here is a sherepreference code which is getting the value from shared pref

```
                    SharedPreferences userGetSession = getSharedPreferences(FRConstants.ACCOUNT_DETAILS_SP, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    sessionVal = userGetSession.getString("login_session_key", null);
                    userID = userGetSession.getString("login_user_id_key", null);
```